# Android Views - How to Configure a "Loose" Piece of View Element Through XML?

Tags: android, layout, view

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

1. Use a TextView in a TabWidget (i.e. call `TabHost.TabSpec.setIndicator(View)` instead of `TabHost.TabSpec.setIndicator(String)`).
2. And i want to configure that TextView in XML instead of building it programatically.

So initially, in my layout XML, i had:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/mainTabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30px"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="30px">
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Now i want to put in the TextView configuration somewhere. It does not actually "belong" nested anywhere within the layout hierarchy. But, since the layout XML have to be a valid XML of course, it can't have more than one root element. So i'm forced to nest the TextView somewhere. Hence i just put it one level below the root (TabHost):

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/mainTabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="30px"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTabIndicatorPreferences"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/tab_name_preferences"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="30px">
    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And in my code i do:

```
final TabHost mainTabHost = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.mainTabHost);
mainTabHost.setup();
final TextView tvTabIndicatorPreferences = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tvTabIndicatorPreferences);
final TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecPreferences = mainTabHost.newTabSpec("tabPreferences");
tabSpecPreferences.setIndicator(tvTabIndicatorPreferences);
tabSpecPreferences.setContent(R.id.scrlTblPreferences);
mainTabHost.addTab(tabSpecPreferences);
```

but there's a problem here. When i try to run the application, i get an exception which says

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

which is by all means logical and reasonable. The TextView is already a child of the TabHost. i can't just set it as the child of another element. (Note: Putting the TextView nested under the TabWidget yields the same thing.)

so i'm forced to call `mainTabHost.removeView(tvTabIndicatorPreferences)` before calling the `setIndicator`.

It works actually, but this way of doing feels very wrong to me. Firstly, i have to put the TextView in the XML where it didn't belong, then in the code remove it from where it didn't belong before using it.

In such a scenario, what's the Right Way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Pull the `TextView` out into a separate layout file (e.g., `res/layout/indicator.xml`).

Step #2: Call `tabSpecPreferences.setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.indicator, null));`

Step #3: There is no Step #3.

Comment: Thank you! Previously, i did do what you say in step #1, but in #2, what i did was to try and call directly findViewById(...) which gave me a NPE. Hence i had thought that all related view elements have to be in the same layout file.

Comment: oh, i also found that doing it this way, i can actually "reuse" the TextView in the layout XML for BOTH tabs. How is it so? i mean, won't it be the case that the TextView would have 2 parents? (or does inflate() create different instances of the view from the same config?)

Comment: Each call to inflate creates a new Java object tree.

Comment: Thanks! i was about to post another question about how to dynamically create N number of a view element configured via XML. But now i know!