# Centering Tab Names On Android

Tags: android, layout, tabwidget

I have followed the official HelloTabWidget Android tutorial and it works perfectly. Next I removed the tab icons and it still works perfectly. Now I would like to center the tabtext both horizontally and vertically in each tab, but I am clueless how. I've tried searching but couldn't find a solution.

I've tried adding *android:layout_gravity* to my main.xml file but it didn't help.

This is my onCreate main.java file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
  TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
  Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

  intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Indkobsliste.class);
  spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1")
                .setContent(intent);
  tabHost.addTab(spec);

  intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Opskrifter.class);
  spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2")
                .setContent(intent);
  tabHost.addTab(spec);

  intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Madplan.class);
  spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3")
                      .setContent(intent);
  tabHost.addTab(spec);

  tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
```

This is the main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This is how my tabs look now:
[image: My tabs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Android API Level >= 4, you can use [TabHost.TabSpec.setIndicator(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29). This allows you to specify any view, so just provide one where you [vertically center your text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432037/how-do-i-center-text-horizontally-and-vertical-in-a-textview-in-android).

If, however, you are running a lower API level, try using the answer from [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618588/workaround-for-the-absence-tabspec-setindicatorview-view-on-android-api-level). It suggests using reflection to set the view even though the API does not publish the required setIndicator method.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. .setIndicator did complain about me using int, so I made a search on Stackoverflow and I saw this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2177045/794806)